# Adding procedural C openGL functions to an iPhone project

Tags: iphone, c, objective-c, xcode, opengl-es

I want to add a few drawing functions to an iPhone project for drawing things. Something like drawTile(x,y,len,wid); which would call openGL to draw a box somewhere. I should just be able to write a procedural C file to do this but the openGL libraries are objective C and I'm getting weird errors. Do I have to make a class for all of my drawing commands and call class methods?

Comment: The errors you are getting contain lots of useful information -- even if they appear cryptic at first. Read them. Learn them. And perhaps, someday, Love them.

Answer (score 0):

no, you should be able to define your own C functions and call them from Objective-C.  Be sure that you  are not defining them within @implementation or @interface blocks.  Also, do you have your includes / imports set up properly?

Comment: the include file is as simple as can be:

#import <openGLES/EAGL.h>
#import <openGLES/ES1/gl.h>
#import <openGLES/ES1/glext.h>
void drawTiles(arguments);

the function definition is in a .m file that goes like:

#import "GLDrawstuff.h"
void drawTiles(arguments)
{
 stuff
}